# Link destinations

Tags: usability, hyperlinks

If the interface that I am working on has 3 lists:

A) Top 10 performing companies

B) 10 recent transactions across those 10 companies

C) Top 10 performing promotions across those companies

The company name is always displayed as a link. Should clicking on the name always take the user to the company's profile page or should it take them to the context within which the name is displayed (e.g Company name is displayed in context (C) above, does the link take the user to the "Promotions" page of the Company or the Company's landing/profile page)?

Answer (score 1):

I think users will have the same doubt, because it is not 100% clear, where this link leads to. There are various implementations on the web, so even doing it this or that way will leave some doubt.

Tu cut it off, I think it would be best to provide two links, indicating where they link to in the same time, like "report >>" and "profile >>".

Comment: Just to clarify the question - the link will not take the user to an external site but instead each company shall have a profile page and then pages for transactions, promotions. So my query is whether clicking on the user name in each of the 3 lists (contexts) should take the user through to the Company profile page or more exactly, to the specific page - eg transaction page for that company. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. I misunderstood you in the first place. Updating my answer.